# Recent Files not seen in Excel start menu

Tags: microsoft-excel, windows-8

This question was asked before but in Windows 8 I can't find the AutomaticDestinations folder even when setting option to show all hidden files & foleders and hence I am putting it up again.

In windows 8 when you pin Excel 2016 to the start menu, it usually has a small arrow which shows your recently opened documents. Mine doesn't show any files and also doesn't show the small arrow. If I open Excel and click on the file menu, I can see all the recently opened documents so they are being recorded somewhere...
Also the shortcut on task bar has the list of recently opened files.

Any idea on how to restore it so I can view them on the start menu - Which I always used before?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide an image of what you're trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

Displaying Recent Files in Windows 8
`Step 1`
Right-click a blank area of the Windows taskbar and select "Properties."

`Step 2`
Click the "Jump Lists" tab, check "Store and Display Recently Opened Items in Jump Lists" and select "OK." Optionally, change the "Number of Recent Items to Display in Jump Lists" to reflect the number of recent items you wish to track for each program.
[Recent Documents shortcut](http://www.techsupportalert.com/content/three-ways-easily-access-your-most-recent-documents-and-files-windows-8x.htm)

Comment: Thanks a lot and sorry for the delay. I was away from my PC. All restored and well. Thanks a ton!